# Locking app in landscape mode only

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad, landscape-portrait

In my app I have the condition of launching my app only in Landscape mode .so for that in will rotate to interface orientation i have done this way:-

```
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
```

But then also my app tries to load in Portrait mode first and in the procedure the screen looks stretching. Am I missing something? Please suggest. Any help will be appreciated

Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the code above is in `-(void)willRotateToOrientation` when it should be placed in `-(BOOL)shouldRotateToOrientation`.

Assuming that is a typo, set the supported orientations in the Info.plist file to LandscapeRight and LandscapeLeft.

Comment: ya done that but still my app when gets loaded ,it tries to load thescreen in portrait mode

Comment: Is the Default.png loading as expected?

Comment: Ok got it frnd i have to write this line in applicationdidfinish launching:-application.statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
it worked

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure Christina's fix in the comments to the other answer doesn't go missed:

```
application.statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
```

I added this in the `didFinishLaunching` app delegate function and it seems to force a view controller refresh which in my case ensured the OpenGL frame buffer was created in the correct dimensions, bizarre that I have to add this though.